# Can you define another string by the text from another string in jquery?

Tags: jquery, string

guys. I was wondering if it's possible to define a string by using an "identifier" string with the text of the string that has to be changed?

I have some code below, where you can see an example.

```
var x1 = 1;
$('.shhi').click(function(){
    var data_id = $(this).attr("data-id");

    var container_class;
    var identifier;
    if(data_id == 1){
        container_class = "information_container";
        identifier = "x1";
    }

    if(identifier == 0){
        $(this).html('<i id="e_' + data_id + '" class="showhide fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Skjul');
        $('#' + container_class).show();
        identifier = 1;
        $('#e_' + data_id).removeClass("fa-plus-circle").addClass("fa-minus-circle");
    }else{
        $(this).html('<i id="e_' + data_id + '" class="showhide fa fa-minus-circle"></i> Vis');
        $('#' + container_class).hide();
        identifier = 0;
        $('#e_' + data_id).removeClass("fa-minus-circle").addClass("fa-plus-circle");
    }   

});
```

So as you can see, I define the x1 string, and then I tell the identifier string that it's the x1 string that has to have a value changed, when it's clicked. But the problem here, is that it doesn't change the "x1" string, probably because it changes the identifier string instead.

Does anyone know a way to get around this? Or would I have to make something that checks the identifier, and then change the x1 etc. out from that? But I'd like it to be clean.

Comment: I don't get what exactly you are trying to do but I imagine `identifier = "x1";` should of been `identifier = x1;` ? Setting identifier's value to be the value of x1

Comment: Doesn't work. And the code is not complete yet, there will be x2, x3 and x4 too. Each one of those are menus.

Comment: I am unclear as to what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Really? How can you be unclear, try to read it again.

Comment: Because it's confusing how you worded this whole thing, why do you think there is no one answering or commenting even. Are you trying to change `x1` with `identifier` because you assigned a string `x1` to `identifier` ?

Comment: There was an "answer" with that. But it didn't work.

Comment: So yes that was what you are trying to do or no that's not what you want to do? That answer also said they are not sure what you are asking if i remember correctly

Comment: Whatever it is you are trying to do, it probably has the wrong approach. Post some html and create a simplified version of a working example and explain what the desired result is when you click. There is probably a simpler way to do whatever it is you want

Comment: I changed it, just did it the messy way..

Comment: Can't really help you unless you can demonstrate the issue you are having